# R conditional loop

Tags: r

I'd like to automatically convert my variables for the purpose of decision tree (32 levels for factor seems to be the limit). I tried a following loop :

```
for(i in 1:39) {
if length(unique(dane.df[,1]))<32 {
as.factor(dane.df[,1])
}  else  length(unique(dane.df[,1]))>32 
{as.numeric(dane.df[,1])} 
}
```

as there are 39 variables in the data frame called dane.df 
I've been using R for two weeks so I'm quite a rookie. I'd really appreciate if you could point out the error (R says there's some trouble with brackets and i cannot be found although it is declared in the first line)

Comment: in R, "if" and "else" are used with brackets: if(x==1)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
dane.df <- data.frame(lapply(dane.df,
  function(x) (if (length(unique(x)) > 32) as.numeric else factor)(x)))
```

Comment: I'm getting : Error in data.frame(lapply(dane.df, function(x) if (length(unique(x)) >  : 
  attempt to apply non-function
how it should be understood?